# Scroll to bottom on component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I want to scroll to bottom as soon as my component renders. I tried to put it in a useEffect and this doesn't work:

```
useEffect(() => {
    scrollRef.current.scrollIntoView();
}, []);
```

If i put an argument in my dependencies it works, but the thing is i don't need that argument to be there.

I've tried to put my scrollRef in my deps , this didn't work. I tried to check with an if statement if the ref isnt null but also this didn't work.

Comment: Which `argument` don't you want to put in the `dependencies` ?

Comment: post your full component code for clarity.